# My webpage is showing white space on right side of header and footer build using html and css

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

My webpage is showing white space on right scrollable side on small screens like mobile phone. It is working fine on large screen but while using on phone it is not able to adjust its size accordingly. Please help.

```css
.row-header {
  padding: 0px auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-color: #9e9e9e;
  padding: 60px 90px 60px 90px;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
  color: floralwhite;
  font-family: 'Libre Caslon Text', serif;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.jumbotron p {
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: antiquewhite;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Add Minimal level of html code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some element is larger than the screen and is not adapting. Check by inspecting element that you will find. Got the project link?

Comment: I will upload it on github ASAP